# How to construct an edge list from data in R?

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this:

```
+--------+-----------+
| Source |  Targets  |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 |   3, 4, 5 |
|      2 |      1, 3 |
|      3 | 6, 10, 11 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Where source is a node in graph data, and then Targets is a list of target nodes, i.e. there's a connection from node 1 to 3, 4, 
d 5 nodes. I want to create an edges list, like so:

```
+------+----+
| From | To |
+------+----+
|    1 |  3 |
|    1 |  4 |
|    1 |  5 |
+------+----+
```

But I'm having trouble getting this done in R. The best I've been able to do yet is the following:

```
extract_edges <- function(row) {
  targets <- strsplit(as.character(locke_relations[row, 3]), ", ")
  df <- data.frame()
  for(t in targets) {
    newrow <- data.frame(from=locke_relations[row,1], to=t)
    df <- rbind(df, newrow)
  }
  df
}
lapply((2:3), extract_edges)
```

`locke_relations` above is the data that is more or less in the form above, and in this code above, I am just processing two rows (rows 2 & 3). It gets me a list containing dataframes that are more or less corrrect:

```
[[1]]
   from    to
1 47678 48378
2 47678 48379

[[2]]
   from    to
1 47686 47804
2 47686 49326
```

But what I really want here is:

```
   from    to
1 47678 48378
2 47678 48379
3 47686 47804
4 47686 49326
```

I could try to find a way to merge the list together but I feel that my whole approach here is off and that in R there is a much more efficient way to do this. Does anyone know how would be the best way to do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `separate_rows` from `tidyr`:

```
tidyr::separate_rows(df, Targets)

#  source target
#1      1      3
#2      1      4
#3      1      5
#4      2      1
#5      2      3
#6      3      6
#7      3     10
#8      3     11
```

Comment: What is `df` here? I am trying to understand how this relates to what I have above.

Comment: `df` is your original data frame that contains all the relations. `locke_relations` in your case. `Targets` is the column name that contains the `to` nodes.

Comment: I'm trying to find documentation for this tidyr library so I can read a definition of the separate_rows function. But I can't find any docs? Can you point me to some @Psidom?

Comment: When I run the above where `lr` is the original dataframe, like so `tidyr:separate_rows(lr, lr[,2])` I get an error: 
"Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions. The following do not: *  lr[, 2]"

Comment: Got it. I see [here](http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/tidyr/man/separate_rows_.html) that targets is the **name** of the column, not the actual data. How can it be that the name is not a string? But yes this appears to work wonderfully.

Answer (score 1):

I will bet on `data.table`( I'm 99% sure it will be fastest and most memory efficient):

```
library(data.table)
data = "1 2,3,4\n2 3,4,5"
dt = fread(data, sep = " ", col.names = c("from", "to"))
res = dt[, .(to = unlist(strsplit(to,",",T), recursive = F, use.names = F)), by = from]
```

EDIT:
probably simpler `base` solution will be even more effective:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
data = "1 2,3,4\n2 3,4,5,6"
dt = fread(data, sep = " ", col.names = c("from", "to"))
edges = lapply(strsplit(dt$to, ',', T), as.integer)
cnts = vapply(edges, length, 0L)
res = data.frame(from = rep(dt$from, cnts), 
                 to = unlist(edges, recursive = F, use.names = F))
```